# Error in 1..n relationship with composite foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing a library with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework Code First 6.1.3.

I get this error when I try to use EF:

> VariableData_AggregationLevelConfiguration_Source: : Multiplicity is
>   not valid in Role 'VariableData_AggregationLevelConfiguration_Source'
>   in relationship 'VariableData_AggregationLevelConfiguration'. Because
>   the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of
>   the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

I want to design this:

A `ProductionOrder` could have one or more `AggregationLevelConfiguration`.
An `AggregationLevelConfiguration` could have zero or more `VariableData`.
An `ProductionOrder` could have one or more `VariableData`.

These are the classes:

```
public class AggregationLevelConfiguration
{
    public byte AggregationLevelConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }

    [ ... ]

    public virtual ProductionOrder ProductionOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<VariableData> VariableData { get; set; }
}

public class VariableData
{
    public string VariableDataId { get; set; }
    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }
    public byte AggregationLevelConfigurationId { get; set; }

    [ ... ]

    public virtual AggregationLevelConfiguration AggregationLevelConfiguration { get; set; }
}

public class ProductionOrder
{
    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }

    [ ... ]

    public ICollection<AggregationLevelConfiguration> AggregationLevelConfigurations { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VariableData> VariableData { get; set; }
}
```

And these are the configuration classes:

```
public class AggregationLevelConfigurationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AggregationLevelConfiguration>
{
    public AggregationLevelConfigurationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(agl => new { agl.AggregationLevelConfigurationId, agl.ProductionOrderId });

        [ ... ]

        HasRequired(agl => agl.ProductionOrder)
            .WithMany(po => po.AggregationLevelConfigurations);
    }
}

public class VariableDataConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<VariableData>
{
    public VariableDataConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(vd => new { vd.AggregationLevelConfigurationId, vd.ProductionOrderId });

        [ ... ]

        HasRequired(vd => vd.AggregationLevelConfiguration)
            .WithMany(agl => agl.VariableData)
            .HasForeignKey(vd => new { vd.AggregationLevelConfigurationId, vd.ProductionOrderId });
    }
}

public class ProductionOrderConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductionOrder>
{
    public ProductionOrderConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(po => po.ProductionOrderId);

        Property(po => po.ProductionOrderId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        [ ... ]

        HasRequired(po => po.Product)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProductionOrders)
            .HasForeignKey(po => po.ProductId);
    }
}
```

But I think it is correct.

What is it wrong? Or, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a one to many relationship using a primary key like this:

```
 HasRequired(vd => vd.AggregationLevelConfiguration)
            .WithMany(agl => agl.VariableData)
            .HasForeignKey(vd => new { vd.AggregationLevelConfigurationId, vd.ProductionOrderId });
```

Since `AggregationLevelConfigurationId, ProductionOrderId` is your primary key in `AggregationLevelConfiguration`, you can only have a one-to-one relationship (according to EF). What you need to do is something like this:

```
 HasRequired(vd => vd.AggregationLevelConfiguration)
            .WithMany(agl => agl.VariableData)
            .HasForeignKey(vd => new { vd.ForeignKeyInVariableData });
```

Where `ForeignKeyInVariableData` is not a primary key in `AggregationLevelConfiguration` (or possibly even a part of a primary key).

Comment: Thanks. In my first version primary in `VariableData` was `HasKey(vd => new { vd.AggregationLevelConfigurationId, vd.ProductionOrderId, vd.VariableDataId });` but I got another error (I don't remember it) when I tried to create the foreign key to `AggregationLevelConfiguration`. Maybe the error was in the column's order in the `.HasForeignKey`.